# Does the C++ standard allow zero-initialization of a POD object with const members?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I've defined a POD that I'm planning on using as an immutable data store. To accomplish this, I've qualified its members as `const`, and am expecting to value-initialize instances (and zero-initialize in some cases). Consider the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    const int value;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo{ };

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to zero-initialize this POD, I get a compiler error in Visual Studio ([C3852](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhh8tk4w.aspx)) because of the `const` qualifier on `Foo::value`. If I remove the qualifier, the code compiles fine.

The exact error message is:

> error C3852: 'Foo::value' having type 'const int': aggregate initialization could not initialize this member
>   const members cannot be default initialized unless their type has a user defined default constructor

According to the standard ([draft n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)), §8.5/5 (**zero-initialization**):

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression,
>   converted to T;
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class
>   subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object’s first non-static named data member is zeroinitialized
>   and padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
>
> — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

and §8.5/6 (**default-initialization**):

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the
>   initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, no initialization is performed.
>   If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class
>   type with a user-provided default constructor.

and §8.5/7 (**value-initialization**):

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the
>   default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>   constructor);
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
>   is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
>   called.
>
> — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

My reading of the standard leads me to believe that my POD should be zero-initialized; not default-initialized. Am I misunderstanding the initialization process described in the standard?

**EDIT:** Considering the details provided in the accepted answer and related comments, this looks like a potential bug in the VS implementation (i.e., the implementation may be based on an outdated version of the standard). I've created a Microsoft Connect ticket to track this, which can be found here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/846222/c-compiler-uses-incorrect-initialization-scheme-for-certain-objects

Comment: You will probably not be shocked to know that this compiles fine with clang, specifically Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)

Comment: @Massa This is with VS2013 (and is also reproducible with the November 2013 CTP compiler).

Comment: Why have const members? Why not just a const Foo?

Comment: You're not zero-initializing with the syntax `Foo foo{ };`. This is aggregate-initialization with less initializers than members, meaning that the data member will be initialized from an empty `{}`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was afraid of that, but was hoping to bet on the chances that I was just misinterpreting the standard. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @dyp: I think it is value-initialization, which in this case means zero-initialization.  (I think Lilshieste has quoted all the relevant ones).

Comment: @WhozCraig does work with clang++-3.5/trunk on linux, too. But does not work with g++-4.8.

Comment: @BenVoigt AFAIK `{}` is always list-init, and at least in later drafts (>= n3485), aggregate init is the first possible option of list-init. n3337 still has value-init before aggregate-init in list-init, though. See the resolution of [CWG DR 1301](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301)

Comment: Where do you read that your object should be zero initialized exactly?

Comment: @dyp I hadn't considered that. You're correct in that if I initialize with the syntax `Foo foo{ 0 };` the code compiles. Now I wonder why it compiles fine on clang. :-)

Comment: @dyp, and there are fewer initializers than members, so the extra members are initialized from an empty list.  So it recurses.  The member isn't an aggregate, so we reach the value-initialization case.

Comment: @BenVoigt True, but I think the error message relates to the deleted default-ctor of the class.

Comment: @Lilshieste I'd guess that this relates to pre/post CWG1301.

Comment: Ugh, the rules in the question have also changed wording *significantly* between that draft and C++11.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's unifun initialization for you ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@dyp's comment that aggregate initialization occurs is correct, but leads to zero-initialization of the member.

```
Foo foo{ };
```

is list-initialization, so we start at 8.5.4.  8.5.4p3 says that (ordering from draft n3690, which matches C++11, and still in n3797)

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - **If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).**
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`, a prvalue `initializer_list` object is constructed as described below and used to initialize the object according to the rules for initialization of an object from a class of the same type (8.5).
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered.  The applicable constructors are enumerated
>     and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7).  If a narrowing conversion (see
>     below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and either `T` is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to `E`, the object or reference is initialized from that element; if a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to `T`, the program is ill-formed.
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by `T` is copy-list-initialized or direct-list-initialized, depending on the kind of initialization for the reference, and the reference is bound to that temporary.
> - **Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.**
> - Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

In the first case, we must visit 8.5.1 for aggregate initialization of the class.  p7:

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there is no brace-or-equal-initializer, from an empty initializer list (8.5.4).

So the `value` member gets list-initialized from an empty initializer list, which recurses into the above rule, reaching the penultimate case, that of value initialization.  And of course from the rules in the question, that is zero-initialization.

---

dyp mentions that prior to n3485, which implemented [CWG 1301](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301), the rule for default construction took precedence, and would try and fail to access the deleted default constructor.

Comment: I think it's important to add that the first two bullet points have been reversed (between n3337 and n3485) probably because of [CWG 1301](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301) If MSVC doesn't implement that, the code is rejected because `Foo foo{ };` is indeed value-initializing the *Foo* object; this leads to calling the deleted default ctor [class.ctor]/5.

Comment: @dyp: isocpp.org doesn't seem to have a newer draft than n3797, which is what I quoted?

Comment: Hm? Yes, but I was referring to an *older* draft. I.e. if MSVC does *not* implement the proposed resolution and clings to some old rules, it might try to value-initialize `foo`.

Comment: @dyp: But, would "is a class type **with a default constructor**" ever have applied here?

Comment: I think so. It has a default constructor, but it's deleted. *"If
there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
as defaulted (8.4). [...] A
defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if: [...] any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array thereof) with no brace-or-
equal-initializer does not have a user-provided default constructor"* n3337 [class.ctor]/5

Comment: @dyp: But the comments in CWG 1301 itself indicate that zero-initialization would occur (admittedly the example is not identical, but it's a similar case where the constructor is defaulted as deleted, not user-defined)  OTOH that example doesn't involve list initialization at all.

Comment: In that example, value-init always happens since it's using `()` and not `{}` for initialization. `{}` can lead to aggregate-init, which I think of an alternative to value/zero/default init.

Comment: Wow, excellent information @BenVoigt and @dyp; I really appreciate it. This is making a lot more sense now. (And my referencing such an old draft didn't help.) I think I'll open a Connect ticket with Microsoft to make sure this is accounted for. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Lilshieste: Please link the Connect ticket here if you open a public one, so we can vote for it.  (And you can link to SO questions in your explanation on Connect, the MS C++ compiler team seems to like knowing that multiple people have already looked at the problem and agree it is a bug.)

Comment: The Connect ticket can be found here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/846222/c-compiler-uses-incorrect-initialization-scheme-for-certain-objects

Comment: @Lilshieste: TY, added my vote.  BTW, based on the error message, the CWG 1301 change isn't the issue here.  The compiler is attempting aggregate initialization.  But it isn't respecting 8.5.1p7 which I quoted in my answer, that requires list initialization of the member.  The compiler used default initialization instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the vote - and correction. I've updated the ticket to remove the incorrect information.